# How to indirectly join two tables

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables

```
perid  firstname lastname 
1       mike      prokosini
2       nick      doug
3       paul      jor
4       riki      thui
5       mun       tyui
```

and second table

```
caseno   name 
13       mike-prokosini
32       nickdoug
33       paul l.jor
34       riki  thui
35       mun kl. tyui
```

I must `join` these tables such that if `firstname` is a substring of `name` `AND` `lastname` is a substring of `name` `THEN` the rows should be connected.

---

I know this is not correct, but I cannot even imagine how we can possibly do this

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table1 , table2 
    WHERE firstname LIKE '%name%' AND lastname LIKE '%name%'
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the actual column values with the wildcard:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name LIKE '%'||t1.firstname||'%' 
                AND t2.name LIKE '%'||t1.lastname||'%'
```